# Charts in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, charts

Which charts are best suitable & responsive for mobile apps made through ionic framework? I tried using angular-nvd3 but it does work well with the mobile device interface. Can anyone suggest me charts which can be used in ionic apps for better responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use the [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) - [Angular charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#getting_started) extension. I've used it before and it works well although you might have to make some UI tweaks if necessary which is a given.

Check out this article
https://dzone.com/articles/using-charts-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app

Comment: I tried angular charts but it does not work well with mobile devices.